# index error array with open cv python respond

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, index-error

im getting this error when running an object detection system
ubnutu 20.04 lts

it starts to run and print some arrays but then the error happens immediately any help would be appreciated
Im using opencv latest version

```
[[1]
 [1]] [[578  25 182 215]
 [604 112 675 608]]
[[ 1]
 [82]
 [18]] [[657 277 623 443]
 [953  16 309 442]
 [636 258 644 461]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jason/Documents/PythonProjects/VoiceAssistant/ObjectDetection.py", line 31, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30), IndexError: list index out of range
```

```py
while True:
    success,img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img,confThreshold=thres)
    print(classIds,bbox)
 
    if len(classIds) > 0:
        for classId, confidence,box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
            cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness=2)
            cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10,box[1]+30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(0,255,0),2)
```

Comment: how about you print `classId, confidence, box` in every iteration of that loop? you're expected to learn debugging and do that before you ask.

Comment: the problem you are facing could come from one of these in my opinion: className, with a classId <= 0, or box with 1 or lkess dimension (probably null I presume if this is the case) -> check the output of "zip" first of all